# How to retrieve sObject picklist field value instead of API name using force:recordData

Tags: picklist, force-recorddata

To get picklist's field value from sObject using SOQL I can use toLabel(FIELD_NAME). Is it possible to do the same with force:recordData component?

[image]

Comment: The term you're looking for is "label". The API name *is* the value of the picklist field. Despite the fact that the Salesforce UI makes it confusing and calls it "Value".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign an object to `targetRecord` as well, e.g.:

```
<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
  recordId="{!v.recordId}" targetRecord="{!v.fullRecord}"
  targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
  recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdated}"
  />
```

You'd retrieve the picklist label as: `{!v.fullRecord.fields.PicklistName.displayValue}`

Comment: Thank you Charles, using targetRecord attribute solves the problem.

Comment: Hi @Charles - I have a similar requirement but here I need to refer to pickilst field values not picklist field label. I am using force:recordData targetFields attribute for this and using it in this way - {!v.simpleRecord.Address_Type__c} - but it returns english value only even in Turkish locale. Can you please help in this

Comment: Picklist options have only one value. Labels are the ones that get translated, not values.